# modification during array traversal

Tags: c++, arrays, traversal

```
int * decrementArrayElements(int numbers[], int size){
    for (int &x: numbers)
    {
        x = x-1;
    }
    return numbers ;
}
```

well as mentioned am trying to dec val of each array ele by 1 by range based for

If I try normal for loop it works

```
int * decrementArrayElements(int numbers[], int size){
    // int n= sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
        numbers[i]=numbers[i]-1;
    return numbers;
}
```

so could pls explain me the reason behind this

Comment: That code doesn't compile.  The first `for` statement doesn't work, because the compiler doesn't know how many elements there are.  That's why you should be using std::vector.

Comment: to **dec val** of each array **ele** - you don't seem to respect SO users that have to read your abbrevations.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `int numbers[]` is actually a pointer, not an array. Range-based loops do not work on pointers.

If you have a C-style array that for whatever reason you need to pass safely to a function, you can use a function template. This allows the compiler deduce the array size from its type.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t size>
int * decrementArrayElements(int (&numbers)[size])
{
    for (int &x : numbers) --x;
    return numbers;
}

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    decrementArrayElements(numbers);
    for (int x : numbers) std::cout << x;
}
```

Outputs:

```
0123
```

In this case the pattern of returning a pointer probably isn't all that useful. It's more likely to be abused. I would lean towards making the function `void`.

You may want to consider using `std::array` instead, which has better encapsulation and (unlike C-style arrays) has copy semantics consistent with other types.

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t size>
std::array<int, size>& decrementArrayElements(std::array<int, size>& numbers)
{
    for (int &x : numbers) --x;
    return numbers;
}

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 4> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    decrementArrayElements(numbers);
    for (int x : numbers) std::cout << x;
}
```